# Show $\delta_c$ is a continuous linear functional

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I would like to prove that for $c\in[a,b]$, $\delta_c:C^\infty[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ with $\delta_c(f)=f(c)$ is a continuous linear functional. To do so, I think I would first like to prove that $\delta_c$ is a linear functional, meaning here that $\delta_c$ is a linear transformation, since $\mathbb{R}$ is already its co-domain. I think it is clear that these properties are satisfied (that for $f,g\in C^\infty[a,b]$, $\delta_c(f+g)=\delta_c(f)+\delta_c(g)$ and for $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, $\delta_c(\alpha f)=\alpha\delta_c(f)$. However, I am not sure how to go about proving that $\delta_c$ is continuous. I think I should use the open sets definition of continuity, but I am not sure how to conceive of an open set in the domain.

Comment: What is the norm on $C^\infty[a,b]$?

Answer (score 1):

The topology for $C^{\infty}[a,b]$ is generated by all the seminorms $\rho_{m}(f)=\sup_{x\in[a,b]}|f^{(m)}(x)|$.

So given that $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ in $C^{\infty}[a,b]$, then $\rho_{0}(f_{n}-f)=\sup_{x\in[a,b]}|(f_{n}-f)(x)|=\sup_{x\in[a,b]}|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|\rightarrow 0$.

By $\delta_{c}(f_{n})=f_{n}(c)$ we get $f_{n}(c)\rightarrow f(c)=\delta_{c}(f)$ since $|f_{n}(c)-f(c)|\leq\rho_{0}(f_{n}-f)$.

So $\delta_{c}(f_{n})\rightarrow\delta_{c}(f)$ is established, as expected.

Comment: Is there any way to approach this without seminorms? I have not learned what these are

Comment: What is the topology for $C^{\infty}[a,b]$ that you have been told?

Comment: The topology for $C^\infty[a,b]$ is defined by the basis composed of sets of the form $\{f|\text{ }|f^{(k_1)}|<\epsilon, |f^{(k_2)}|<\epsilon,...,|f^{(k_n)}|<\epsilon\}$ and translates, where $\{k_1,...,k_n\}$ is any finite subset of $\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$.

Comment: We are saying the same topology actually. Anyway, then put all $k_{1}=\cdots=k_{n}=0$ and deduce from uniform topology the result.